# Switch to parameter doctype-system in an XSLT file

Tags: xslt

Can you help me, this is my first experience in XSLT:
I need to pass the `doctype-system` parameter:

Can you verify that my XSLT is correct?

```
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method='xml' indent='no' version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' doctype-public='xxx' doctype-system="{$pURL}" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements=""/>
  <xsl:param name="pURL" select="'127.0.0.1:8080/dtd/?param'"/>
    ; 
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="param"></xsl:variable> <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@ | ">         
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@ | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [tour]. You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: Please update your question to add information. Make it easy for us to understand and answer your question!

Comment: I incorporated your XML/XSLT code from your comment and made it well-formed by fixing some tags.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to parameterize such an attribute of the `xsl:output` element then you need to use an XSLT 3.0 processor like Saxon 9 PE or EE or Exselt or Altova 2017, there you can use a [static](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#static-params) `xsl:param` and a [shadow attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#shadow-attributes) as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsl:param name="doctype-uri" static="yes" as="xs:string" select="'http://example.com/foo.dtd'"/>

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" doctype-public="foo" _doctype-system="{$doctype-uri}"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With earlier versions of XSLT you would need to write two stylesheets where the first takes a normal parameter and generates the second with the desired attribute.

In general, if your aim is to redirect requests for a DTD to a local copy, you should rather look into XML catalogues instead of implementing a change in the DOCTYPE for each document.